# Questions about iAd?

Tags: ios, iad

I have implemented iAd into my iOS application but this is my first time using it so I have a couple of questions.

Note: I have tried to find answers to all these questions but I'm not sure about the accuracy of answers on forums from 2011.

1. How does Apple define an impression for iAds? So, is there a sort of time frame which has to be met for an impression to count? I think I read 30 seconds somewhere but I'm not sure if this is accurate?
2. I only have a single `ViewController` in my application. I am using `SpriteKit` so everything is screens are changed my presenting new `SKScene` objects.  The application starts with the ViewController presenting a scene. Since my ad banner will only load once (at the start of the app), does this mean I will only get one impression each time someone opens my app (please say no)?
3. Where can I find information on eCPM, CPC, and stats of the sort? I couldn't find anything in the iAd Apple Documentation. Again, I only have varying numbers I got off of old forums.
4. How do I decide what kind of advertisements to integrate? Right now I only have a single ad banner. Am I limiting myself with just an ad banner?
5. Is there any source that would have information on how revenue works with iAds?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to find detailed and reliable information pertaining to your questions.

My answers are based on my experiences with iAd.

1. An impression, I believe, is counted if your application requests an ad and loads its successfully. The 30 seconds you're referring to is the refresh rate at which another banner ad will be requested. For example, ad requested>ad shown>30 seconds have passed>request another ad>show new ad>30 seconds have passed>repeat...
2. I'd imagine this ad banner is shown throughout your app so it will refresh with new ads as I mentioned in answer #1. Each new ad will count as another impression.
3. All of these stats and many more, minus CPC, are available through [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa). There is a link to [iAd](https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/#app_homepageConnect.woa) once you've logged in.
4. This is up to you. You could integrate interstitial ads, which are full screen ads, in addition to banner ads. Interstitial ads usually have higher eCPM rates so there is more potential for increased revenue, but they come at the cost of being highly invasive and annoying to users.
5. This question is very vague. I can tell you that iAd pays 70% of its revenue to developers. Besides that you may want to check out [this mass amount of information](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/).